# Sync 2 Comboxes C#

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource, synchronization

Hi I'm struggling to come up with an effecient method for syncing 2 comboxes unsing c#. The 2 comboxes contain the same values minus the current selected values from either combobox.

i.e.

Datasource = "A" "B" "C" "D"

combobx 1 current selected item = "A"
combobx 2 current selected item = "B"

Available values needed

combobox 1 = "A" "C" "D"
combobox 2 = "B" "C" "D"

Whats the best way to acheive this? I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to programming windows Forms

This is what I tried

Yep, no joy... here's what I tried

```
    static List<string> ds = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

    BindingList<string> b1 = new BindingList<string>(ds);
    BindingList<string> b2 = new BindingList<string>(ds);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = b1;
        comboBox2.DataSource = b2;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (b2.Remove((string) comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            b2.Remove((string) comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
        if (!b1.Contains((string) comboBox2.SelectedItem))
        {
            b1.Add((string) comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (b1.Remove((string)comboBox2.SelectedItem))
        {
            b1.Remove((string)comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
        if (!b2.Contains((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            b2.Add((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try with yours ..

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = b1;
        comboBox2.DataSource = b2;

        Boolean lDoing1;
        Boolean lDoing2;
    }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lDoing1)
        {
         Return;
        }
        if (b2.Remove((string) comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            lDoing2 = True ; 
            b2.Remove((string) comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            lDoing2 = False ;
        }
        if (!b1.Contains((string) comboBox2.SelectedItem))
        {
            b1.Add((string) comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lDoing2)
        {
         Return;
        }
        if (b1.Remove((string)comboBox2.SelectedItem))
        {
            lDoing1 = True ;
            b1.Remove((string)comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            lDoing1 = False ;
        }
        if (!b2.Contains((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            b2.Add((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that method but it triggers the selected Index change event and led to the items falling out? when you remove from 1 combobox you need to add to the other, creating an evil loop

Comment: Sorry, that creates an infinite loop

Comment: @user1641194 : Little mistake .. you can try it again